# Offline malware / script scanner for webfiles (PHP and HTML)

Tags: malware, php, spam, antimalware

I have downloaded an entire copy of a website that has been used as a spam relay. I think I have tracked down the problem to a loophole in a contact form (now closed, but was not used, but still accessible hence why it was missed), however I would like to check the website files for injected code.

Will a standard anti virus such as BitDefender do the job, or can anyone recommend a scanner (preferably standalone) that can scan PHP files and find known injections.

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: hello and welcome to security.se Please be aware that requests for product recommendation are not considered suitable for this site. However, given your specific question, I suggest you rewrite it to ask how you should vet you PHP code (since AVs will simply not work in your case anyway).

Comment: See: [Malware scanner for websites code](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32138/3474)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, malicious code in your PHP file is not a virus or a trojan. Most end user anti-malware tools do not scan for these types of things.

The malicious actions in your web app may be legitimate commands that make sense in a different context. You may want to look into static code analysis tools which analyze code for software design errors.